# Remove whitespace from a regex search in a file

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to remove all whitespace from a selected string search using regexp. The code works but it continues to return an error that I'm not sure how to resolve ...?

```
elif searchType =='2':
      print "  Directory to be searched: c:\Python27 "
      directory = os.path.join("c:\\","SQA_log")
      userstring = raw_input("Enter a string name to search: ")
      userStrHEX = userstring.encode('hex')
      userStrASCII = ' '.join(str(ord(char)) for char in userstring)
      regex = re.compile(r"(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII )))
      choice = raw_input("Type 1 to search with whitespace. Type 2 to search ignoring whitespace: ")
      if choice == '1':
           for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
              for file in files:
                  if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
                     f=open(os.path.join(root, file))
                     for i,line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                         result = regex.search(line)
                         if regex.search(line):
                            print " "
                            print "Line: " + str(i)
                            print "File: " + os.path.join(root,file)
                            print "String Type: " + result.group()
                            print " "


                     f.close()
      re.purge()              
      if choice == '2':
         for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
             for file in files:
                 if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
                    f=open(os.path.join(root, file))
                    for i,line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
                        result = regex.search(re.sub(r'\s', '',line))
                        if regex.search(line):
                           print " "
                           print "Line: " + str(i)
                           print "File: " + os.path.join(root,file)
                           print "String Type: " + result.group()
                           print " "

                    f.close()  


                        re.purge()
```

This is the error it returns:

```
Line: 9160
File: c:\SQA_log\13.00.log
String Type: Rozelle07

Line: 41
File: c:\SQA_log\NEWS.txt
String Type: 526f7a656c6c653037

Line: 430
File: c:\SQA_log\README.txt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\SQA_log\cmd_simple.py", line 226, in <module>
    SQAST().cmdloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cmd.py", line 142, in cmdloop
    stop = self.onecmd(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\cmd.py", line 219, in onecmd
    return func(arg)
  File "C:\SQA_log\cmd_simple.py", line 147, in do_search
    print "String Type: " + result.group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: The ``userStrASCII = ' '.join(str(ord(char)) for char in userstring)`` is probably the culprit. It adds spaces to the regular expression, and those spaces only match with ``regex.search(line)``, not with ``regex.search(re.sub(line, ...)``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `regex.search` fails on `line` with whitespaces stripped, but succeeds when whitespaces are there. You haven't given `regex`'s definition, so I can't tell you why that happens, but if you replace `if regex.search(line)` with `if result:` you shouldn't get that error.

The reason for the error is that `re.search` returns a special value, `None`, when it doesn't find any match, instead of a match object. `None` always evaluates to `False` inside boolean expressions, so you can use it in an `if` statement, but it doesn't have any attributes, and that's why `result.group()` fails when result is `None`.

BTW: You probably want to use `re.gsub(r'\s+', '', line)` instead of `re.sub(r'\s', '', line)` if you want to remove **all** occurrences of whitespace in `line` and not just the first one.

Fixed code:

```
for i,line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
    result = regex.search(re.gsub(r'\s+', '', line))
    if result:
       print ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are doing here:

`result = regex.search(re.sub(r'\s', '',line))`

you substituted one space with blank, and then what are you searching for ? The error message is quite clear. `result.group()` has nothing.

Comment: I put a dummy string with whitespace in a file that the regexp would match by ignoring the whitespace =>re.sub(r'\s', '',line). The original regexp I didn't list because it works fine => regex = re.compile(r"(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII )))